# I deleted my aliases file, but my aliases are still in my bash session - how can I recover them?

Tags: bash, terminal, alias

I had a ton of aliases defined and I use them all the time.  I have a terminal session open now in which all the aliases are valid and working.  However, the .bash_aliases file in which they were defined has been deleted. How can I expand or recover my aliases from my terminal session?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Simply use the command `alias` which prints out all definitions in a format `bash` can read in again:

```
$ alias
alias second='again'
alias test='hello'
```

So to recover, simply use

```
$ alias > .bash_aliases
```

Comment: Will this escape everything correctly?

Comment: Do you have something special in mind? For example no problem with `alias weired='echo \\$hello'`.